# Trying to understand how you use the request in Actions

Tags: scala, playframework

I want to understand how the request variable comes in scope when you do:

```
def test(): Action = {  request =>

}
```

Reference:
https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Action.scala

**Could you also bring in other variables in scope?
How does this work under the covers in Scala?**

In a relation issue, I created my own custom Action and I was confused as to what type it really is?

I did something like the Authentication example:

```
class AuthenticatedRequest[A](val username: String, request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)

object Authenticated extends ActionBuilder[AuthenticatedRequest] {
  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (AuthenticatedRequest[A]) => Future[SimpleResult]) = {
    request.session.get("username").map { username =>
      block(new AuthenticatedRequest(username, request))
    } getOrElse {
      Future.successful(Forbidden)
    }
  }
}
```

Reference: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaActionsComposition

In my controller I wanted to pass the 'request' as a parameter to a method, but I couldn't figure out what exact type it was.  When I tried AuthenticatedRequest it said I have to pass in type parameters.

Comment: Have you read this: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaActions?

Comment: @I.K. I see ok.  But how does it do this?  Can someone create a simple class that behaves like an action but slimmed down just to get the point across to me?

Comment: Not sure why you are confused about `Action`; it is just a type to represent a function which maps a `Request` to a `Result`. From the source code: `def apply(request: Request[A]): Future[Result]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Action is a function that takes a Request[A] object as argument and returns a Result, and thats the type of your test method. Consider a simple example

```
type StrLen = String => Int

/**
 * A function that returns another function from String to Int
 */
def test2(): StrLen = { someString => someString.length() }
```

OR

```
def test2(): StrLen = str: String => { /* body */
   str.length()
}
```

Comment: In your first example, where is someString coming from?  That is what I don't get.  You are not passing someString as a parameter

Comment: follow the type and ask yourself, how to define a function literal

Comment: oh I see ok. Hmm, ok it is starting to sink in now.